# Which font license should I buy for use in a company logo?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I would like to know which font license I should buy for use in a company logo? I am going to use the logo in my web application, in advertisements and everywhere the company logo appears.

Comment: See [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/30443/5489) - might answer some of the questions you have regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd typically buy the standard license. With a few exceptions, most commercial fonts allow you to use it as you see fit. If there is an exception, you'll see it in the license.

Do note, however, that the font you decide to use for your logo is not typically also used for everything else. That's not a hard and fast rule, but typical.

Comment: What if there is no standard license available for that font and still I want to use it for company logo?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Do you have a specific Font in mind? Most all fonts come with a license.

Comment: For example, see this.. http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/interstate/ There is no standard license. Here, which one should I use?

Comment: @JavaTechnical The license is listed on the page you linked to: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/interstate/licensing.html that is the standard license for that font.

Comment: Thanks. If i have 1000 employees in my company, should I buy 1000 licenses? I am not actually using them on the employee desktop computers directly. I just need it for company logo, so mostly it will be an image that will displayed on the web.

Comment: @JavaTechnical to create a logo, you buy one license...for the designer that's creating the logo. They will convert it into an image so other's won't need a license to see the logo.