# Where can I find a legal website to buy a font for my logo?

Tags: fonts, logo, web-fonts, trademark

I want to register my brand as a trademark. I've almost completed my logo design. The only thing left is the font.

I've found thousands fonts and websites online. The problem is that I'm not sure if I can use these fonts for my logo. 
I've read that I need to read the license before using/buying the font. But what if that font is already created by another designer?

I'm looking for the most respected websites that offer fonts that I can use for my logo with absolutely no problems.

My question is: How do I know that a website is 100% legal and sells fonts that I can use with no problem?

Comment: What is the font you are currently using and which site is it being offered on?

Comment: Related: [Which font license should I buy for company logo?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35182/which-font-license-should-i-buy-for-company-logo) & [Using the font Avenir commercially for logo design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/using-the-font-avenir-commercially-for-logo-design)

Answer (score 1):

As its for your own logo, you only have to buy a licence for yourself. So you don't have to worry about giving clients access to your font which will be bring up different licence concerns. As its a logo you just need a desktop/print licence.

As all licensing will vary, when you found your font read their licence page. But check out these sites to view the difference in licences as a guide.

http://www.fonts.com/info/services/licensing-options
https://processtypefoundry.com/licensing/our-license-agreement

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that a website is 100% legal and sells fonts that you can use with no problem?

This is pretty easy: you use a trusted font reseller. A font reseller has contracts with every font vendor they sell for, and pays commission on every sale. Sites like [fontspring.com](https://www.fontspring.com) and [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com) are examples of sites that would give you 100% confidence in your purchase.

Almost universally, font licenses allow you to use fonts to create logos. Oftentimes, the only exception to that rule would be if the font had a dingbat image in it. In that case, that particular symbol probably wouldn't be allowed as a logo.